# Display of Java Component is delayed

Tags: java

I'm facing a strange behavior from the Java Runtime(VM) when I'm trying to display a label or progress bar on the screen when something happens.
The scenario is like this:
the user will press a button to do a certain action 
this action is a kind of process on the DB which could take some seconds
I'm displaying a message in a Jlabel field which is already in the form but set to be invisible when the form opens.
Then when the user presses a button I'm setting this label to be visible and do some processing and then set it back again invisible as it was, which is very simple logic.
problem is the Jlable is displayed after the processing is done and not before.
The same problem with happens also a progress bar.
Any explanation why is this happening?

here a sample of the code

```
Mylable.setVisible(false);  defaullt status when the form opens

Event Occurend (user clicked a button)
   Mylable.setVisible(true); 
      ....... do some process here
   Mylable.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: could you post the real code please?

Comment: You're blocking the UI thread.

Comment: Perform do some process here in a separate thread and ensure that your event handler returns back. When the process is complete use SwingUtilities#invokeLater to set the label to invisible from that thread.

Comment: I did it in a different Thread and it's working fine. Thanks for the hint